# libx is needed when installing rpm on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, centos7

During the installation of a rmp on Centos 7, I got error message as below

```
libX11.so.6()(64bit) is needed
libXau.so.6()(64bit) is needed
libxcb.so.1()(64bit) is needed
libXext.so.6()(64bit) is needed
libXft.so.2()(64bit) is needed
libXi.so.6()(64bit) is needed
libXrender.so.1()(64bit) is needed
libXtst.so.6()(64bit) is needed
```

Just wondering if there is a single package to have all of those libx included?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of those should be in the repos already. You should be using `yum install`  to install your RPM and *not* `rpm`, as this will provide you automatic dependency resolution.

Comment: This is true too, I should have mentioned that.  yum will resolve dependencies and ask if you want to install them, whereas rpm will just abort because they aren't met.

Answer (score 2):

If you do `yum whatprovides '*/libX11.so.6*'` you will see what package provides that, same as the others.  I believe there are 4 or 5 packages involved with that.  libXrender I think might be a separate package, along with libXft and libXtst.